# Why is the radical ideal of the homogenization of an ideal the homogenization of the radical of said ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal. If $I^{h}$ is the homogenization of that ideal, defined by $I^{h}:= \langle f^h: f \in I\rangle$ that is the ideal generated by the homogenized elements of I, then why is $\sqrt{I^h}=\sqrt{I}^h$?

I know, that for one single element $(f^h)^n=(f^n)^h$, but I have trouble representing an arbitrary element in $I^h$, because they do not need to be homogeneous anymore.

Comment: Welcome to the website! Does this help to answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111660/why-is-the-homogenization-of-a-radical-ideal-radical?rq=1 Or is there still more which is unclear?

Comment: Unfortunately I am still stuck. My ideal is an abitrary one and I do not see how computing $f_*$ might help me.

Comment: I guess I just meant that the if the homogenization of the radical is radical, then it is equal to its own radicalization, i.e. the radicalization of the homogenization (of the radicalization). So if you can show that the homogenization of the radicalization is equal to the homogenization, then you are done. Actually that sounds circular to me now that I say it out loud though.

Answer (score 1):

I use the notation $I^*$ for the homogenization of $I$.

Take $F\in\sqrt{I^*}$ homogeneous. Then $F^N\in I^*$ for some $N$. But then $F^N_*\in I$ which means $F_*\in\sqrt I$. So that $(F_*)^*\in(\sqrt I)^*$. But then $F=X_{n+1}^r(F_*)^*\in (\sqrt I)^*$. For a general $F=\sum F_i$, each homogeneous component $F_i$ is in $\sqrt{I^*}$ since the radical of a homogeneous ideal is still homogeneous (verify).

Now take $F\in(\sqrt{I})^*$. Then $F=\sum{A_iG_i^*}$ where $G_i\in\sqrt{I}$. So there is an $N$ large enough so that  each $G_i^N\in{I}$. And so there is an $M$ large enough so that $F^M\in I^*$ or $F\in\sqrt{I^*}$.